# Database Encryption: MSSQL 2008+ Database Encryption and use in Coldfusion

Tags: sql-server, database, csv, encryption, coldfusion

Our client sends CSV file (average 0.3 million records) that file. we import in our **Microsoft SQL** database.

Is there a way while importing data from CSV file, I can encrypt (SHA & Other)?? How can I send queries(select,insert & update) to database? from **coldfusion** or **Microsoft SQL**.

Application Server: Coldfusion 9,9+ and Lucee 
Database: Microsoft SQL Server 2008+

For Example im already using in mysql. Im looking same in MSSQL:

**MYSQL Example**

**INSERT:**

```
INSERT INTO List_encrypted 
(fname,Lname,email) 
Values
(AES_ENCRYPT(fname,'dbkey'),
AES_ENCRYPT(Lname,'dbkey'), 
AES_ENCRYPT(email,'dbkey')) 
from List_encrypted
```

**SELECT**

```
select CAST(AES_DECRYPT(fname,'dbkey')AS CHAR (50)) AS FirstName, 
CAST(AES_DECRYPT(Lname,'dbkey')AS CHAR (50)) AS LastName, 
CAST(AES_DECRYPT(email,'dbkey')AS CHAR (50)) AS email 
from List_encrypted
```

**MYSQL IMPORT CSV DATA**

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE  'C:\filename.txt'
INTO TABLE List_encrypted
CHARACTER SET utf8
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES
(fname,lname,email,stamp_dt)
SET 
fname = AES_ENCRYPT(@fname,'dbkey'),
lname = AES_ENCRYPT(@lname,'dbkey'),
email  = AES_ENCRYPT(@email,'dbkey'),
stamp_dt        = now();
```

**This is what i did in MSSQL:**
*I don't know how to encrypt, while importing*

```
CREATE TABLE List_encrypted
(
 ID int not null identity(1, 1) primary key,
 LName varchar(255),
 FName varchar(255),
 email varchar(255),
);

BULK INSERT [List_encrypted]
FROM 'C:\filename.txt'
WITH 
(
  FIELDTERMINATOR = '" ; "',
  ROWTERMINATOR = '\r\n'
)
```

Comment: Are you sure that encrypting that database at the *individual value level* is a good idea in the first place?

Comment: @Tomalak why im doing some fields because these are most important   fields. what is the best practice? you suggest ?

Comment: Read through this fist: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510663(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: @Tomalak  is there anyway i can do one column ?? while importing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one way you can bulk import in temp table then physical table.

Example: *Create Table*

```
CREATE TABLE #t1
(
    NAME varchar(255)
);
```

*Import in temp table*

```
BULK INSERT [#t1]
FROM 'C:\CSV\names.txt'
WITH 
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = '" | "',
ROWTERMINATOR   = '\n'
)
```

*Import in physical table & ENCRYPT*

```
select 
   CAST(DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('dbkey',Encrypted) AS varchar(8000)) 
   AS Encrypted 
from t1
```

Comment: it worked thanks although i was looking something else it seems like this the solution.